# The pervious index isn't updating by pressing previous in REACT

Tags: reactjs, indexing

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const UseIterator = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers();
    }, []);

    const fetchUsers = () => {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const { results: userList } = data;
                const {
                    name: { first, last },
                    picture: { thumbnail }
                } = userList[0];

                setUsers([{ name: `${first} ${last}`, picture: thumbnail }]);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            });
    }

    const handlePrevious = () => {
        setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => Math.max(prevIndex - 1, 0));
    }

    const handleNext = () => {

        setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => Math.min(prevIndex + 1, users.length - 1));
        fetchUsers()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? 'Loading...' : (
                <>
                    <button onClick={handlePrevious} >Previous</button>
                    <button onClick={handleNext} >Next</button>

                    <div>
                        <img src={users[currentIndex].picture} alt={users[currentIndex].name} />
                        <div>{users[currentIndex].name}</div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default UseIterator;
```

As you can see by pressing the next button the state changes and updates in the browser but when I press previous the state dosen't change and nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

I have tried making a new state variable called previousIndex but still coudn't keep track of the previous index variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `users` array hold a single user.

When you trigger `handleNext` you call `fetchUsers` to place a new user in the `users` array, but you're not calling that when pressing `previous`.

I'd recommend changing `fetchUser` to append the new users to `users` and then just use that index:

```
setUsers(p => [ ...p, { name: `${first} ${last}`, picture: thumbnail }]);
```

---

Updated Demo:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const UseIterator = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers();
    }, []);

    const fetchUsers = () => {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const { results: userList } = data;
                const {
                    name: { first, last },
                    picture: { thumbnail }
                } = userList[0];

                setUsers(p => [ ...p, { name: `${first} ${last}`, picture: thumbnail }]);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            });
    }
    
    const handlePrevious = () => {
        setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => Math.max(prevIndex - 1, 0));
    }

    const handleNext = () => {

        setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => Math.min(prevIndex + 1, users.length - 1));
        fetchUsers()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? 'Loading...' : (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <button onClick={handlePrevious} >Previous</button>
                    <button onClick={handleNext} >Next</button>

                    <div>
                        <img src={users[currentIndex].picture} alt={users[currentIndex].name} />
                        <div>{users[currentIndex].name}</div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<UseIterator />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```